# MySQL - Get row and average of rows

Tags: mysql

First of all I'll just warn everyone that I'm something of a rookie with MySQL. Additionally I haven't tested the example queries below so they might not be perfect.

Anyway, I have a table of items, each one with a name, a category and a score. Every 12 hours the top item is taken, used and then removed.

So far I've simply been grabbing the top item with

```
SELECT * FROM items_table ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1
```

The only issue with this is that some categories are biased and have generally higher scores. I'd like to solve this by sorting by the score divided by the average score instead of simply sorting by the score. Something like

```
ORDER BY score/(GREATEST(5,averageScore))
```

I'm now trying to work out the best way to find averageScore. I have another table for categories so obviously I could add an averageScore column to that and run a cronjob to keep them updated and retrieve them with something like

```
SELECT * FROM items_table, categories_table WHERE items_table.category = categories_table.category ORDER BY items_table.score/(GREATEST(5,categories_table.averageScore)) DESC LIMIT 1
```

but this feels messy. I know I can find all the averages using something like

```
SELECT AVG(score) FROM items_table GROUP BY category
```

What I'm wondering is if there's some way to retrieve the averages right in the one query.

Thanks,

YM

Comment: "I'm something of a rookie with MySQL" what do you mean by rookie?

Comment: @imran: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3Arookie

Comment: I've been using it for about 3 years but I'm self taught and only learned about normalised databases about 6 months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the query that calculates the averages:

```
SELECT   i.*
FROM     items_table i JOIN (
           SELECT   category, AVG(score) AS averageScore
           FROM     items_table
           GROUP BY category
         ) t USING (category)
ORDER BY i.score/GREATEST(5, t.averageScore) DESC
LIMIT    1
```

Comment: Looks perfect, I'll test it out in my own code in a few hours.

Comment: Didn't just look perfect, worked perfect too. Thankyou very much!